# make a facebook icon a drop down menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a customer that owns a business. This business has an individual facebook page for each location. Several pages on the website have the facebook icon. I want to turn this icon into a drop down menu. So when you hover over the facebook icon a menu drops down where you can select the location facebook page your interested in.

Answer (score 0):

You can find everything you want on this site : http://bootsnipp.com

try this : http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/share-on-social-networks

replace the share icon with Facebook icon, and put what you want on the drop down menu.